# How to use `tf.scatter_nd` with multi-dimensional tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a new tensor (`output`) with the values of another tensor (`updates`) placed according to `idx` tensor. The shape of `output` should be `[batch_size, 1, 4, 4]` (like an image of 2x2 pixels and one channel) and `update` has shape `[batch_size, 3]`.

I've read Tensorflow documentation (I'm working with gpu version 1.13.1) and found `tf.scatter_nd` should work for my problem. The issue is that I cannot make it work, I think I'm having problems understanding how I have to arange `idx`.

Let's consider `batch_size = 2`, so what I'm doing is:

```py
updates = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])  # shape [2, 3]
output_shape = tf.constant([2, 1, 4, 4])
idx = tf.constant([[[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]])  # shape [2, 3, 2]
idx_expanded = tf.expand_dims(idx, 1)  # so I have shape [2, 1, 3, 2]
output = tf.scatter_nd(idx_expanded, updates, output_shape)
```

I expect it to work, but it doesn't, it gives me this error:

`ValueError: The outer 3 dimensions of indices.shape=[2,1,3,2] must match the outer 3 dimensions of updates.shape=[2,3]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 3 and 2 for 'ScatterNd_7' (op: 'ScatterNd') with input shapes: [2,1,3,2], [2,3], [4]`

I don't understand why it's expecting `updates` to have dimension 3. I thought `idx` has to make sense with `output_shape` (that's why I used `expand_dims`) and also with `updates` (specify the two indices for the three points), but it's obvious I'm missing something here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been playing around with the function and I have found my mistake. If anyone is facing this problem, this is what I did to solve it:

Considering `batch_size=2` and `3` points, `idx` tensor must have shape `[2, 3, 4]`, where first dimension correspond to the batch from where we are taking `update`value, second dimension must be equal to the second dimension of `updates` (number of points per batch) and the third dimension is `4` because we need `4` indices: [batch_number, channel, row, col]. Following the example in the question:

```py
updates = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])  # [2, 3]
idx = tf.constant([[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]], [[1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]]])  # [2, 3, 4]
output = tf.scatter_nd(idx, updates, [2, 1, 4, 4])

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(output))

[[[[2. 1. 0. 0.]
   [3. 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. 0.]]]


 [[[5. 0. 0. 0.]
   [6. 4. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 0. 0. 0.]]]]
```

This way it's possible to place specific numbers in a new tensor.